# Convergence of infinite series of expectation of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expected-value

Consider a sequence of non-negative random variables $\{X_n\}$ such that $X_n\overset{a.s}\longrightarrow X$, such that $\mathbb{P}(X>0)=1$.

I have to show that the below infinite series is convergent:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb{E}(e^{-e^nX_n})$$

Intuitively, I can see how this might happen, since the exponent is negative, $e^n\uparrow\infty$ and $X_n$ converges almost surely to a positive random variable.

But I am having trouble figuring out how to show this mathematically.

The only way I could think of proceeding was to show that for large $n$, we can have $X_n$ to be arbitrarily close to $X$ and if $X$ was almost surely greater than some small positive constant, then $X_n$ is also positive, for all large n. And this ensures the convergence of the series.

But this is incorrect because there need not exist a particular $N$ after which $X_n$ is arbitrarily close to $X$ over the entire sample space (the convergence need not be uniform).

I do not know how else to proceed now, it would be great if someone could help me with an idea or give me a hint.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot prove a **false statement**.

---

To construct a counter-example, let $U$ be uniformly distributed over $[0, 1]$ and consider the random variables $X_n$ and $X$ defined by

$$ X_n = \mathbf{1}_{\{U > \frac{1}{n}\}} + e^{-n}\mathbf{1}_{\{U \leq \frac{1}{n}\}}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
X = 1.
$$

Then $X_n \to X$ a.s. and $\mathbf{P}(X = 1) = 1$, but

$$ \mathbf{E}[e^{-e^n X_n}] \geq \mathbf{E}[e^{-1}\mathbf{1}_{\{U \leq \frac{1}{n}\}}] = \frac{1}{en}. $$

Hence it follows that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{E}[e^{-e^n X_n}] = \infty. $$

Comment: +1. I would think that the result is fasle even when $X_n\equiv X$.

Comment: @geetha290krm, Indeed, if we set $X_n = X = e^{-1/U}$ for $U\sim\text{Uniform}(0,1)$, then $$\{X\leq e^{-n}\}=\{U\leq\tfrac{1}{n}\}\qquad\text{and hence}\qquad \mathbf{E}[e^{-e^nX}]\geq\frac{1}{en},$$ so the sum will diverge.

Comment: Thanks. For the benefit of other visitors to the page you could put this example also inside the answer.

Comment: @notacompactspace, I guess the detail may actually change the answer. So the best approach is to post another question with all the details of the problem included, so that we do not fall into the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).